# Hola, complementar un código para convertir unidades para visual basic studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

```
Public Class Form1
    ' Variables de clase
    Private Resultado3 As Double
    Private Resultado4 As Double
    Private Resultado2 As Double
    Private Resultado3a As Double
    Private Resultado4a As Double
    Private Resultado2a As Double
    Private Resultado5 As Double

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        ' Código actual del método
    End Sub

    ' ... Otros métodos ...

    Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
        ' Llamar a la función de verificación antes de realizar las operaciones
        If VerificarTextBoxVacio(TextBox2) Then
            Resultado3 = 0.0 ' O cualquier valor predeterminado que desees

            If ComboBox3.Text = "m" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text * 0.342
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "in" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 34
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "ft" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text * 89
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "yd" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 45
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "cm" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 12213
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "mm" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 4
            End If
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y pon tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta el problema que estás teniendo. Además, pon en las etiquetas con qué lenguaje estás trabajando. El IDE (Visual Studio en este caso) nada tiene que ver con tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*No se que unidades quieres pero aqui para transformar yardas ya que el código no se bien que necesitas*

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    ' Declaración de la variable para las conversiones a yardas
    Dim conversionYardas As Double = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Configurar el ComboBox con las unidades
        ComboBoxUnidades.Items.Add("Pies")
        ComboBoxUnidades.Items.Add("Pulgadas")
        ComboBoxUnidades.Items.Add("Metros")
        ComboBoxUnidades.Items.Add("Centímetros")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonConvertir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonConvertir.Click
        ' Validar la selección del ComboBox
        If ComboBoxUnidades.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor, selecciona una unidad.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return
        End If

        ' Realizar la conversión a yardas
        Select Case ComboBoxUnidades.SelectedItem.ToString()
            Case "Pies"
                conversionYardas = Double.Parse(TextBoxValor.Text) / 3 ' 1 pie = 3 yardas
            Case "Pulgadas"
                conversionYardas = Double.Parse(TextBoxValor.Text) / 36 ' 1 pulgada = 36 pulgadas
            Case "Metros"
                conversionYardas = Double.Parse(TextBoxValor.Text) * 1.09361 ' 1 metro = 1.09361 yardas
            Case "Centímetros"
                conversionYardas = Double.Parse(TextBoxValor.Text) * 0.0109361 ' 1 cm = 0.0109361 yardas
        End Select

        ' Mostrar el resultado en el Label
        LabelResultado.Text = conversionYardas.ToString("N2") & " yardas"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonAbrirVentana_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAbrirVentana.Click
        ' Crear y mostrar la nueva ventana
        Dim nuevaVentana As New Form2()
        nuevaVentana.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonSalir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSalir.Click
        ' Cerrar la aplicación
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Configurar la imagen y el nombre en la nueva ventana
        PictureBoxImagen.Image = My.Resources.ImagenEjemplo ' Cambia 'ImagenEjemplo' al nombre real de tu imagen
        LabelNombre.Text = "Nombre de la Imagen"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonVolver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonVolver.Click
        ' Volver a la ventana principal
        Dim ventanaPrincipal As New Form1()
        ventanaPrincipal.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Por qué hablas en 3ª persona?

Answer (score -1):

Aquí esta el código solicitado para conversiones a unidades en Visual Basic 2015

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ResultadoHPOrig, Ei, Resultado3, Resultado3a, Resultado4, Resultado4a, Resultado2, Resultado2a, ResultadoFormateadoHP, Potencia, Potencia2 As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Label9.Text = "0" Or TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or ComboBox1.Text = "" Or ComboBox2.Text = "" Or ComboBox3.Text = "" Or ComboBox4.Text = "" Or ComboBox5.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Todas las entradas deben tener asignado un valor.")
            Label9.Text = "" ' Establecer el Label9 en "0"
            Return 
        End If

        If Resultado3 > 0 AndAlso Resultado4 > 0 AndAlso Resultado2 Then
            If Not (Double.TryParse(Label6.Text, Resultado3) AndAlso Double.TryParse(Label7.Text, Resultado4) AndAlso Resultado3 > Resultado4) Then

                MessageBox.Show("El valor en la entrada de alimentación debe ser mayor que el valor de salida de tamiz.")
                Return 
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox5.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Resultado3 > 0 AndAlso Resultado4 > 0 AndAlso Resultado2 Then
            Dim C As Double = 1.46
            ' Calcular el resultado
            Dim ResultadoHP As Double = C * Math.Round(Resultado2a, 2) * Math.Round(Ei, 2) * ((1 / Math.Sqrt(Math.Round(Resultado4a, 2))) - (1 / Math.Sqrt(Math.Round(Resultado3a, 2))))
            ResultadoHPOrig = ResultadoHP

            '   If Double.TryParse(Label1.Text.TrimEnd("h", "p"c), ResultadoHP) Then
            
            Dim resultadoConvertido As Double

            Select Case ComboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString()
                Case "hp"
                    ' Formatear el resultado con cuatro dígitos
                    ResultadoFormateadoHP = ResultadoHP.ToString("0.####")
                    ' Mostrar el resultado en Label9
                    Label9.Text = ResultadoFormateadoHP 'hp

                Case "libras fuerza"
                    ' Convertir de hp a lb-f
                    resultadoConvertido = ResultadoHPOrig * 550
                    ' Mostrar el resultado en el Label10
                    Label9.Text = resultadoConvertido.ToString("0.####") 'lb f

                Case "watts"
                    ' Convertir de hp a watts
                    resultadoConvertido = ResultadoHPOrig * 745.7
                    ' Mostrar el resultado en el Label10
                    Label9.Text = resultadoConvertido.ToString("0.####") 'w

            End Select

        End If
        '  End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

        ' Verificar si TextBox3.Text no está vacío
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text) Then
            ' conversiones solo si TextBox2 tiene un valor válido

            Resultado4 = 0.0
        If ComboBox4.Text = "m" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text * 3.2808
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "in" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 12
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "ft" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text * 1
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "yd" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 3
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "cm" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 30.48
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "mm" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 3
        End If

        Else
            ' TextBox1.Text vacío, establecer Label7 en "0"
            Label7.Text = "0 ft"
            Label9.Text = ""
            Resultado4 = 0.0
        End If

        ' resultado con cuatro dígitos
        Dim ResultadoFormateado4 As String = Resultado4.ToString("0.####")

        ' Asignar el resultado formateado al Label7
        Label7.Text = ResultadoFormateado4
        Resultado4a = Resultado4

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox4.SelectedIndexChanged
        Resultado4 = 0.0 ' O cualquier valor predeterminado que desees

        ' TextBox3.Text no está vacío
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text) Then
            ' Conversiones solo si TextBox2.Text tiene un valor válido

            If ComboBox4.Text = "m" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text * 3.2808
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "in" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 12
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "ft" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text * 1
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "yd" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 3
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "cm" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 30.48
        ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "mm" Then
            Resultado4 = TextBox3.Text / 3
        End If

        Else
            TextBox1.Text está vacío, establecer Label8 en "0"
            Label7.Text = ""
        End If

        ' Formatear el resultado con cuatro dígitos
        Dim ResultadoFormateado4 As String = Resultado4.ToString("0.####")

        ' Asignar el resultado formateado al Label7
        Label7.Text = ResultadoFormateado4
        Resultado4a = Resultado4
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label9.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

        ' TextBox2.Text no está vacío
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
            ' Realizar conversiones solo si tiene un valor válido

            Resultado3 = 0.0
            If ComboBox3.Text = "m" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text * 3.2808
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "in" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 12
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "ft" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text * 1
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "yd" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 3
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "cm" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 30.48
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "mm" Then
                Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 3
            End If

        Else
            ' Si TextBox1.Text está vacío, Label8 en "0"
            Label6.Text = "0 ft"
            Label9.Text = ""
            Resultado3 = 0.0
        End If

        ' Formatear el resultado con cuatro dígitos
        Dim ResultadoFormateado3 As String = Resultado3.ToString("0.####")
        ' Asignar el resultado formateado al Label6
        Label6.Text = ResultadoFormateado3
        Resultado3a = Resultado3
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
        Resultado3 = 0.0 ' O cualquier valor predeterminado que desees

        ' TextBox2.Text no está vacío
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
            ' Conversiones solo si TextBox2.Text tiene un valor válido

            If ComboBox3.Text = "m" Then
            Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text * 3.2808
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "in" Then
            Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 12
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "ft" Then
            Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text * 1
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "yd" Then
            Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 3
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "cm" Then
            Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 30.48
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "mm" Then
            Resultado3 = TextBox2.Text / 3
        End If

        Else
            ' Si TextBox1.Text está vacío, establecer Label6 en "0"
            Label6.Text = ""
        End If

        ' Formatear el resultado con cuatro dígitos después del punto decimal
        Dim ResultadoFormateado3 As String = Resultado3.ToString("0.####")
        ' Asignar el resultado formateado al Label6
        Label6.Text = ResultadoFormateado3
        Resultado3a = Resultado3

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Resultado2 = 0.0 ' O cualquier valor predeterminado que desees

        ' TextBox1.Text no está vacío
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
            ' Realizar conversiones solo si tiene un valor válido

            If ComboBox2.Text = "Ton/H" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 60
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Ton/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text * 1
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Kg/H" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 60000
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Kg/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Lb/h" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 132277.2
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Lb/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 2204.62
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Oz/h" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 2116440
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Oz/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 35274
            End If

        Else
            ' "0 T/min"
            Label8.Text = ""
        End If

        ' Formatear el resultado con cuatro dígitos después del punto decimal
        Dim ResultadoFormateado2 As String = Resultado2.ToString("0.####")

        ' Asignar el resultado formateado al Label8
        Label8.Text = ResultadoFormateado2 & " T/min"
        Resultado2a = Resultado2
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Resultado2 = 0.0

        ' Verificar si TextBox1 no está vacío
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
            ' Conversiones solo si TextBox1.Text tiene un valor válido

            If ComboBox2.Text = "Ton/H" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 60
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Ton/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text * 1
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Kg/H" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 60000
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Kg/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Lb/h" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 132277.2
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Lb/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 2204.62
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Oz/h" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 2116440
            ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Oz/min" Then
                Resultado2 = TextBox1.Text / 35274
            End If
        Else
            ' Si TextBox1 vacío, establecer Label8 en ""
            Label8.Text = ""
            Label9.Text = ""
        End If

        ' Resultado con cuatro dígitos después del punto decimal
        Dim ResultadoFormateado2 As String = Resultado2.ToString("0.####")

        ' Asignar el resultado formateado al Label8
        Label8.Text = ResultadoFormateado2 & " T/min"
        Resultado2a = Resultado2

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        ElseIf Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." And Not TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(".") Then
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        ElseIf Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." And Not TextBox3.Text.IndexOf(".") Then
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        ElseIf Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." And Not TextBox2.Text.IndexOf(".") Then
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.Text = "CARBÓN" Then
            Ei = 11.37
            Label5.Text = Ei & " EI"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "COBRE" Then
            Ei = 13.13
            Label5.Text = Ei & " EI"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "CORAL" Then
            Ei = 10.16
            Label5.Text = Ei & " EI"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "GRAFITO" Then
            Ei = 45.03
            Label5.Text = Ei & " EI"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "PLATA" Then
            Ei = 17.3
            Label5.Text = Ei & " EI"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ' Crear una nueva instancia de Form1
        Dim nuevoForm1 As New Form1()
        ' Mostrar el nuevo Form1
        nuevoForm1.Show()

        ' Cerrar el Form1 actual
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ' Cerrar la ventana actual
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ¿Código solicitado? ¡[es.so] no es un sitio al estilo _El Rincón del Vago_! Además, ¿cuál fue la pregunta que hizo AP (el autor de la pregunta)? Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_ y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo espera que el OP de mas contexto de lo que ha intentado hacer y lo que espera. ya que existen usuarios que vandalizan con votos negativos las respuestas de esas preguntas.

Comment: tambien ten en cuenta dejar una explicacion elaborada de que cosas corregiste o cambiaste del codigo para tener una mejor idea de tu respuesta, te invito a participar del chat para conocer como funciona el sitio:  [enlace](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Comment: ¿Solicitado? ¿chatGPT?